# How to print Data to Word 2013 template using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, word-2013, word-template

I have a problem to print data to Word document template in 2013 , Actually i can able to print data in word 2010(Using XSD file) using vb.net , but 2013 doesn't accept xmlnodes(i know they remove xml nodes in 2013).How can i print the data in word2013 .

My scenario is :

1. I create template with different font styles and Header colors with three tables .
2. I need to dynamically add the rows based on my data ( in all my tables ).

Please guide how can i move....

Comment: I scrapped all the xsd files code and went for using WordprocessingDocument and the templates as docx. Works well. If you want I have the code and can post it as answer. But its not quite what you are asking for, I know.

Comment: Yes please Archlight , it may be help to me ... and thank you for your response ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer for xsd files. But by request i put this forward.

Opening the docx as a memory stream and in this example I have a table with a caption.

That is in the word document there is a table and when you select it and right click->properties->Alternative Text -> title.

This title is the thing that I search for in the word document to know where to add my stuff. There are probably much better ways of doing this. But this makes the document editable for administrators and as long as they dont delete the table they can edit it as they see fit.

```
dim mem As MemoryStream
dim doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true)         
Dim tableProperties = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants(Of TableProperties)().Where(Function(tp) tp.TableCaption IsNot Nothing)
For Each tProp As TableProperties In tableProperties
    If tProp.TableCaption.Val.ToString() = "DatatableTitle" Then
        Dim tbl = DirectCast(tProp.Parent, Table)
        InsertTableRows(tbl, myListOfThings)
    End If
Next

Private Function CreateTableCellText(myText As String) As TableCell
    Dim run = New Run()
    Dim runProperties = New RunProperties()


    runProperties.Append(New RunFonts() With { .Ascii = "Times New Roman" })
    runProperties.Append(New FontSize() With { .Val = "16" })
    run.PrependChild(runProperties)
    run.Append(New Text(myText))
    Dim p = New Paragraph()
    p.Append(run)
    Dim td = New TableCell()
    td.Append(p)
    Return td
End Function

Private Sub InsertTableRows(tbl As Table, patients As List(Of MyTableList))
    'var refRow = tbl.Elements<TableRow>().ElementAt(1); // the first is the header.
    tbl.Elements(Of TableRow)().ElementAt(1).Remove()

    For Each patient As MyTableList In patients
        Dim tr = New TableRow()
        tr.Append(CreateTableCellText(patient.DepartmentName))
        tr.Append(CreateTableCellText(patient.PatientLastName))
        tbl.Append(tr)
    Next
End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyTableList
    Public Property DepartmentName() As String
        Get
            Return m_DepartmentName
        End Get
        Set
            m_DepartmentName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_DepartmentName As String

    Public Property PatientLastName() As String
        Get
            Return m_PatientLastName
        End Get
        Set
            m_PatientLastName = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_PatientLastName As String
End Class
```

And adding checkboxes and such is no problem, just create them in word, open the word document in a texteditor and copy the xml from the document and add it as new paragraph and then use firstChild.InnerXml and copy the xml into the text. and then append it